# Math proof inequality

Tags: inequality, exponential-function, binomial-coefficients, proof-explanation

Prove that for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$,
$4^{n+4}≥(n+4)^4$

I tried using induction.  I got that $4\cdot 4^{k+4} \geq 4 \cdot(k+4)^4$ by the inductive hypothesis but i am not sure how to prove the rest for $k+1$

Answer (score 1):

All you need is that
$$\left(\frac{n+5}{n+4}\right)^4\le 4.$$
But for $n\ge0$,
$$\left(\frac{n+5}{n+4}\right)^4\le
\left(\frac{5}{4}\right)^4=\frac{625}{256}<4.$$

Answer (score 0):

Guide:

We want to show that $$4(k+4)^4 \geq (k+5)^4,$$

That is  $$(\sqrt2k+4\sqrt2)^4 \geq (k+5)^4,$$

For $k$ positive, we want to show that

$$\sqrt{2}k+4\sqrt{2} \geq k+5$$

Answer (score 0):

Use the  binomial theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem

We have:
$$4^{n+4}=(1+3)^{n+4}>\binom{n+4}{4}3^4>(n+4)^4$$ for all $n\geq3$ and check $n=1$ and $n=2$.

Comment: how do you know that inequality is true?

Comment: @tskgreen I added something. See now.